# Kusama - Provided Host header is not whitelisted

Tags: substrate

having started the kusama node as a service with

```
polkadot --port 30333 --rpc-external --rpc-port 9933  --ws-external --ws-port 9944
```

Now im trying to call the node with a POST request for http://IP:9933 and this JSON payload:

```
{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "state_getMetadata"}
```

Im gettings as a 403 forbidden response:

> Provided Host header is not whitelisted.

Any ideas whats missing in the setup?

Comment: Hi Vindberg, can you please support our Substrate StackExchange proposal: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to configure CORS header. You can either add `--rpc-cors=all` to disable origin validation or pass a allowed origin like `--rpc-cors=https://your.website.url`

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/fc3adc87dc806237eb7371c1d21055eea1702be0/core/cli/src/params.rs#L346

```
/// Specify browser Origins allowed to access the HTTP & WS RPC servers.
/// It's a comma-separated list of origins (protocol://domain or special `null` value).
/// Value of `all` will disable origin validation.
/// Default is to allow localhost, https://polkadot.js.org and https://substrate-ui.parity.io origins.
/// When running in --dev mode the default is to allow all origins.
#[structopt(long = "rpc-cors", value_name = "ORIGINS", parse(try_from_str = "parse_cors"))]
pub rpc_cors: Option<Cors>,
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. Using Postman to make requests I didn't believe this was necessary. It worked thanks!

Comment: This question/response pair is amazing and solved my exact problem, thanks to you both.